# How meaningfull is Activity.mayStop()?

Tags: gwt, gwt-activities

I am wondering if there is any non trivial use case for the `com.google.gwt.activity.shared.Activity#mayStop` method.

1. The `com.google.gwt.place.shared.PlaceController.Delegate#confirm` is a blocking one, so you cannot use a different `Delegate`, that is using callbacks. I really do not know why this is implemented in a blocking manner because the GWT guys always say that user interactions should be handled asynchronously.
2. The `mayStop` method is always called. Even if the `ActivityManager` would return the same `Activity` and the UI would not change. So the activity has to check for instance if the user has unsaved changes and if a place change whould really result in discarding the unsaved data. I think this check could be done more easily before calling `placeController.goTo(new Place())`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6228#c1 **TL;DR:** asynchronous handling opens the door to too many edge cases, bugs, confusion, and differing needs/wishes as to how it should work.
2. The activity that does the `goTo` is not necessarily the one that needs to do checks in `mayStop`. In the case it is, then if it does the check before doing the `goTo` (and then transit to a state where the `mayStop` will return `null`), then in the case there is another activity with *unsaved changes*, this will result in two confirmations being asked to the user.
   It's also possible to listen to `PlaceChangeRequestEvent`s and conditionally call `setWarning`, instead of doing the check in `mayStop`. That way you have access to the place you're navigating to; but it couples your activity with the places and their mapping to activities (e.g. a *list activity* might be displayed on a *details place* on the desktop, but not on mobile); that's the responsibility of the `ActivityMapper`s.
   Also, don't forget navigation can be triggered by the browser (user navigating in the browser's history). The thing is: on the web, the user is in control.
   All in all, it's probably better (and simpler) to simply do the `goTo`s and rely on `mayStop` to ask for confirmation. (the activity could also disable the buttons/links triggering `goTo` in the case there are *unsaved changes*, so navigation could only be triggered by other activities).

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I did not consider the point, that the navigation could be triggered by i.e. the Backbutton.